# Need help loading an OBJ and MTL file in Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm experiencing an odd issue while trying to load an OBJ and MTL file in Three.js using it's OBJMTLLoader() function and just can't seem to figure it out, or find a solution on Google. I have my index.html file inside of a folder, and also in that same folder is my js folder, which includes all external js files that I wrote for my project along with the three.js r68 library. Also in my root project folder is a folder named 'obj', which includes all of my obj files and their corresponding mtl files.

I initially started my project under a Windows system and was able to load everything just fine, no problem at all, but now I switched to my personal Linux system and I started seeing this problem and am unable to load any of my obj/mtl files any longer.

The error I am receiving is '**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**' and I've tried printing out my 'loader' variable and it simply shows me in the console that it's an object of type OBJMTLLoader. Any thoughts on this?

EDIT: The first file is js/main.js, and the next one is index.html.

```js
const WIDTH = 1200;
const HEIGHT = 700;
const VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
const ASPECT_RATIO = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
const NEAR = 0.1;
const FAR = 10000;

var renderer,
  camera,
  scene;

var pointLight, pointLight2;
var xrot = 0.0025,
  yrot = 0.0025;

$(document).ready(function() {

  // setup renderer, camera, perspective, etc.
  initScene();

  $('#loadfile').change(getLoadedFile);
  $('input[type=range]').eq(0).change(showYRot);

  // lights
  pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
  pointLight.position.x = -10;
  pointLight.position.y = 50;
  pointLight.position.z = 130;

  scene.add(pointLight);

  pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
  pointLight2.position.x = 0;
  pointLight2.position.y = 50;
  pointLight2.position.z = 500;

  scene.add(pointLight2);

  var render = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

    $(scene.children).each(function() {
      if (this !== camera && this !== pointLight) {
        this.rotation.x = xrot;
        this.rotation.y += yrot;
      }
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };
  render();

});

function initScene() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAR, FAR);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.add(camera);

  camera.position.z = 250;

  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  $('div#container').append(renderer.domElement);
}

function getLoadedFile(evt) {
  var fileList = evt.target.files;
  var filename = fileList[0].name;

  if (filename.substring(filename.length - 4, filename.length) == '.obj') {
    var obj = filename;
    var mtl = filename.substring(0, filename.length - 4) + '.mtl';

    console.log('adding ' + filename + ' to scene.');
    loadOBJMTLModel(obj, mtl);
  }
}

function loadOBJMTLModel(obj, mtl) {

  var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
  loader.load('obj/' + obj, 'obj/' + mtl, function(object) {
    scene.add(object);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>OBJ Model Previewer</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
    div#container {
      width: 1200px;
      height: 700px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
  </style>
<!--  <script src="js/main.js"></script> //-->

  <body>
    <h3>Choose file to load</h3>
    <input id="loadfile" type="file" />
    <br />
    <div id="container"></div>
    <br />
    <span></span><br />
    <span></span><br />
    <br />
    <span>Y Rotation: </span><input type="range" min="0.0" max="0.1" step="0.001" />
    <span id="yrot"></span>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which line exactly is giving you that error?

Comment: I'm not sure as it's giving me a couple of new errors now. I'll edit my question with the new info.

Comment: what is in your js/main.js? add the content.

Comment: @SagarV I've added an edit that explains what each file is. The first source file in my post is js/main.js.

Comment: Will check it once I reach my room

Comment: OBJMTLLoader is deprecated. you must use MTLLoader and OBJLoader together. You can view a traditional example here: view-source:https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html There have also been numerous updates to objloader2.js available @ https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js

Comment: @Radio I was unaware that it was deprecated. I will try what you suggested and hopefully it will run.

Comment: @Radio I'm a dumbo. I removed OBJMTLLoader and replaced everything with the other two classes and it's working again without any errors. Thank you! Please add your comment as an answer now so I can mark this as solved and reward you with points.

Comment: @hRdCoder added, thanks.

Comment: BTW, since you were aware of and using the deprecated OBJMTLloader class, you should probably use a package manager such as npm or bower to get the latest threejs, which at the time of this comment is r85, rather than using threejs.org links.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tend to not use package managers but I probably will need to bite the bullet sooner or later. Thankfully, I've already been using the latest version of jQuery, not 1.11.0 anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested.

OBJMTLLoader is deprecated. you must use MTLLoader and OBJLoader together. You can view a traditional example here: view-source:threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

There have also been numerous updates to objloader2.js available @ https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js

For a little more digging, see my previous answer for automated MTL loading here: [Is there a way to load a mtl using the path in the obj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122400/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-mtl-using-the-path-in-the-obj-file/43143457#43143457)