# obj file and mtil file path

Tags: asp.net, 3d, three.js

I would like to display a 3D model with perfect rendering on the website.
It does not find the path of mtl and obj. 
I am writing a program with visual studio for web and wish to be on the website with the master page. And mtl and obj are in a folder named models.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default10.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default10" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ObjectLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
                var width = window.innerWidth;
                var height = window.innerHeight;
                renderer.setSize(width, height);
                // 화면 비율(aspect ratio)을 나타냅니다. (넓이를 높이로 나눈 값)
                camera.aspect = width / height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            });

            // 스크롤
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            /*
            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setPath('models/');
            mtlLoader.load('mi.mtl', function (materials) {
                materials.preload();

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.setPath('models/');
                objLoader.load('mi.obj', function (object) {
                    object.position.y = -95;
                    scene.add(object);
                });
            });/**/
            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            var objpath = 'models/mi.obj';

            loader.load(objpath, function (object) {
                loadMats(object, objpath);
            },
            function (eve) { console.log("obj progress", eve) },
            function (xhr) { console.log("obj error", e) }
            );
            var loadMats = function (obj, objpath) {
                imgloader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                imgloader.setPath(objpath.substring(0, objpath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                imgloader.load(obj.materialLibraries[0],
                    function (materials) {
                        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                        objLoader.load(objpath, function (object) {
                            scene.add(object);
                        },
                            function (eve) { console.log("obj progress", eve) },
                            function (xhr) { console.log("obj error", e) }
                        );
                    },
                    function (eve) { console.log("mtl progress", eve) },
                    function (xhr) { console.log("mtl error", e) }
                );
            }
            //
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                camera.position.z = 3;

                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.8);
                scene.add(ambientLight);

                // game logic
                var update = function () {
                    // cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                    // cube.rotation.y += 0.005;
                };

                //draw Scene
                var render = function () {
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                };

                // run game loop (update, render, repeat)
                var GameLoop = function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);

                    update();
                    render();
                };

                GameLoop();
        </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. I wrote this code and explained the caveats here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122400/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-mtl-using-the-path-in-the-obj-file/43143457#43143457

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to load a mtl using the path in the obj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122400/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-mtl-using-the-path-in-the-obj-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mime type for .obj and .mtl extensions.
In Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="text/plain" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mtl" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you are using an hosting, you can change it from ASP.NET Settings, too.
And if it doesn't work try this, too. Maybe you need to remove global setting before add mimeMap

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".obj" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="text/plain" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mtl" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mtl" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If mimeType of .obj files arn't text/plain. Use (with removing global settings or without),

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="application/wavefront-obj" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mtl" mimeType="application/wavefront-obj" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```